# How to create RTSP using a Local video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, vlc, libvlc

I want to create an RTSP using a local video on the system.

I tried using the FFmpeg but was able to create a UDP stream using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -v 0 -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:23000`

Comment: Try using cvlc. What did work? What did not?

Comment: I need RTSP stream but not able to create one using local video

Comment: I tried using VLC Gui but the rtsp does not becin from start when we start it reading can you help with the cvlc command to create one??

Comment: There are examples around, I guess on the VLC homepage. I just needed it recently.

Comment: I tried all around didn't find anything, have you tried the solution ?

Comment: I think used something I found at https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/